# how to convert grayscale image to rgb RGB image?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm trying to convert a grayscale image to rgb image,does tensorflow.js have an function like tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb in tensorflow to do this?

Comment: Generally it helps if you try something, and if it doesn't succeed then people here can help you out. For example, if you look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/grayscale_to_rgb does this suffice or is there something else you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb` convert a 3d tensor with a single channel to a 3d tensor with 3 channels where the 3 channels have the same intensity. The result is still a grayscale image. This can be done with the following

```
const transformed = tensor.mul([1, 1, 1])
```

The above uses broadcasting to augment the size of the last dimension to 3

Converting a grayscale image to a colorful image on the other hand is not a trivial task. To achieve it, some models have been trained only for that purpose